# How to generate EDIFACT messages (IFIMIN) from .net (C#)?

Tags: .net, generator, edifact

I am about to start a project where I need to generate an EDIFACT message (message type: [IFTMIN](http://www.unece.org/trade/untdid/d00a/trmd/iftmin_c.htm)). Since my project is .net based (C# + asp.net) I am looking for advise on generating EDIFACT messages in .net.

Is there a free (possibly open source) library that will help generate an EDIFACT message?
Are there any pitfalls in regards to encoding etc.?

If anybody has some example code I would love to have a look.

Best regards, Egil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not been able to find a framework for edifact that we could use. In the end we used [FileHelpers Libabry](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/) to read the files and coded the rest by hand. FileHelpers lib does support record based files, much like edifact.